# PlCrashReporter Crash Report not showing backtrace for iOS

Tags: ios, crash-reports, backtrace, plcrashreporter

I have integrated the **PLCrashReporter Framework** into my iOS app,

pls. ref : https://www.plcrashreporter.org/

http://rajatwork.com/?p=113

which works completely fine. It generates the crash log, convert it into protobuff format and sends an email in a text file format(with the protobuff data). The problem here is, the data which is decoded, does not match with the device crash log, i.e. it does not show the backtrace(present in the device log).

Below is the device crash log consisting of Last Exception Backtrace  which is not present in the PLCrashReport.

```
Last Exception Backtrace:

0   CoreFoundation                  0x33b2329e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b84b97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a6de88 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 160
3   Project                         0x000ffede -[MyQuestionsViewController viewDidLoad] (MyQuestionsViewController.m:44)
4   UIKit                           0x3594a590 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 360
5   UIKit                           0x3599f146 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 22
6   UIKit                           0x3599f08c -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
7   UIKit                           0x3599ef70 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 28
8   UIKit                           0x3599ee94 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 268
9   UIKit                           0x3599e5d4 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 60
10  UIKit                           0x3599e4bc -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 320
11  UIKit                           0x3598cb8e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 854
12  UIKit                           0x3598c82e -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 34
13  Mirai                           0x00133334 -[HomeViewController goToMyQuestions:] (HomeViewController.m:364)
14  UIKit                           0x35a160c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68
15  UIKit                           0x35a16072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
16  UIKit                           0x35a16050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
17  UIKit                           0x35a15906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
18  UIKit                           0x35a15dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
19  UIKit                           0x3593e5ec -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
20  UIKit                           0x3592b7fc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
21  UIKit                           0x3592b116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
.
.
.
```

So is there a way to add "BackTrace" using PLCrashReport ?

Comment: Did this happen while working on xCode or while using the app?

Comment: this is the actual Device Logs which consist of BackTrace but the Crash Report generated by PlCrashReporter doesnt have it.

Comment: But it tells you there is something happening inside the ** MyQuestionsViewController**, maybe you can check the class and also post us the code so we can check it too. Seems like there is something going wrong inside `viewDidLoad`. Maybe you could show the different crash log of PLCrashReport to compare whats exactly the difference

Comment: Actually we are trying to generate the Crash Log by code (programmatically), and we know the cause of the crash i.e. Exception in MyQuestionsViewController, the Given crash log is not being created through Code using PlCrashReporter.

Comment: Please use the PLCrashReporter discussion list for such issues: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/plcrashreporter